# python copy() and remove()

Tags: python, list, copy

I want to write copy() and remove(i) in same line, but it seems not working. However, when i separate into two lines, the answer is correct.

just curious why these two programs have different output

**program 1**

```
x = [1,2,3,4,5]
d = [1,4,5]

for i in d:
    temp = x.copy().remove(i)
    print(temp)
```

**output:**

```
None
None
None
```

**program 2**

```
x = [1,2,3,4,5]
d = [1,4,5]

for i in d:
    temp = x.copy()
    temp.remove(i)
    print(temp)
```

**output:**

```
[2, 3, 4, 5]
[1, 2, 3, 5]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: `remove` is an *in-place* operation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is happening because the `remove()` operation is an in-place operation, meaning it updates the list itself and returns `None`, which is why you are seeing the returned value as `None`.

What you can do instead is use the walrus operator `:=` to capture the result of `copy()`. That object would then be updated by the `remove()` function.

```
x = [1,2,3,4,5]
d = [1,4,5]

for i in d:
    (temp := x.copy()).remove(i)
    print(temp)
```

Output

```
[2, 3, 4, 5]
[1, 2, 3, 5]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```